# Solving for a variable in a polynomial with arbitrary x

Tags: functions, polynomials, cubics

The graphs of the functions $f(x)=x^3+(a+b)x^2+3x−4$ and $g(x)=(x−3)^3+1$ touch. Express a in terms of b.

The solution in the textbook is $a=−\frac{(27+11b)}{11}$

I've tried looking for a worked solution, but couldn't find anything.
Help would really be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This means there is a real solution to $f(x)=g(x)$. In other words, $f(x)-g(x)$, which is a quadratic, has a real zero.

Comment: Thanks @MPW. I've tried letting the two functions be equal, but can't get the right solution.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if they mean that the graphs of $f$ and $g$ share a mutual tangent, in which case $f’(x) =g’(x)$ for that $x$ as well.

Comment: In fact, graphs are touching if both $f(x)=g(x)$ and $f'(x)=g'(x)$ hold for some real $x$. So, MPW's approach in the second comment is the proper one.

Answer (score 0):

Set the functions equal to each other and expand to get $$x^3-9x^2+27x-27+1=(a+b)x^2+3x-4,$$ and this simplifies to give you $$(a+b+9)x^2-24x+22=0.$$ If we require the functions to intersect in just one point, then the equation $$24^3-88(a+b+9)=0$$ must be true (by setting the discriminant to $0$), which when you solve for $a$ gives $$a=-\frac{27}{11}-b,$$ as desired.

Comment: The question doesn’t specify touching at only one point

Comment: Did you assume only one point of intersection or figure it out? Anyways it gets the right answer so thanks.